# How to register bean programatically in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to find a way how to programatically create bean in quarkus DI, but without success. Is it possible in this framework? It seems that `BeanManager` does not implement the needed method yet.

Comment: Quarkus does not support CDI extensions and its `BeanManager` indeed does not support some things, to register a bean programmatically you will need to write a Quarkus extension.

Comment: Like @JanMartiška says, you need to write an extension in order to do this. The basic reason is that in Quarkus all bean resolution is done at build time.

Comment: Can you give more infor on what you want to achieve? Because usually creating beans via a bean producer is enough.

Comment: Bean producer? Can you please explain?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/3.1.4.Final/en-US/html_single/#producer_methods

Comment: Hi @Mejmo have you managed to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 11):

First, we should clarify what *"programatically create bean"* exactly means.

But first of all, we should define what *"bean"* means. In CDI, we talk about beans in two meanings:

1. Component metadata - this one describes the component attributes and how a component instance is created; the SPI is `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean`
2. Component instance - the real instance used in application; in the spec we call it "contextual reference".

The metadata is usually derived from the application classes. Such metadata are "backed by a class". By "backed by a class" I mean all the kinds [described in the spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#implementation). That is class beans, producer methods and producer fields.

Now, if you want to **programatically obtain a component instance** (option 2), you can:

1. Inject `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`; see for example [the Weld docs](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup)
2. Make use of `CDI.current().select(Foo.class).get()`
3. Make use of quarkus-specific `Arc.container().instance(Foo.class).get()`

However, if you want to **add/register a component metadata** that is not backed by a class (option 2), you need to add an extension that makes use of quarkus-specific SPIs, such as [BeanRegistrar](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#synthetic-beans).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Quarkus equivalent of Spring `@Configuration` then you want "[bean producer](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#simplified-producer-method-declaration)" (as mentioned in comments above)

Here is an example (in Kotlin) of how to manually register a clock:

```kotlin
import java.time.Clock
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces

@ApplicationScoped
class AppConfig {

   @Produces
   @ApplicationScoped
   fun utcClock(): Clock {
       return Clock.systemUTC()
   }  
}
```

- `@Produces` is actually not required if method is already annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`
- `@ApplicationScoped` at class level of `AppConfig` is also not required

Although, I find those extra annotations useful, especially if are used to Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your beans using Instance:

```
@Inject
public TestExecutorService(final ManagedExecutor managedExecutor,
                           final Instance<YourTask> YourTask) {
    this.managedExecutor = managedExecutor;
    this.YourTask= YourTask;
}
```

And if you need to create more than one Instance you can use the managed executor:

```
tasks.forEach(task -> managedExecutor.submit(task::execute));
```

Keep in mind that depending on the way you start the bean you may need to destroy it and only the "creator class" has its reference, meaning you have to create and destroy the bean in the same classe (you can use something like events to handle that).

For more information please check: [CDI Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html)